# What evidence do I need to declare tutoring income on my income tax?

Tags: canada, income-tax, self-employment

What evidence do I need to declare tutoring income on the Canadian federal income tax form?
I am doing tutoring with students and want to declare it.
Can I make copies of the checks I receive?

Comment: Sure, copies of checks. But also keep a notebook of dates/names/money received. In the States, the IRS will be happy people are claiming income many will try to avoid declaring.

Comment: I have rental income and simply use a duplicate receipt book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been a private tutor on and off for about 30 years, in three countries, so I understand your concerns!

I always kept records as though it was a real business - even if I only had one student I kept records of dates/times/names, and also tracked where the money went (I never spent it straight up - it always got deposited to complete the paper trail; yes, this is paranoia on my part).

I've never been asked to prove anything with regards this income (although I have no Canadian experience). It's always been a case of tell the tax folks and make sure my arse is covered if they come asking questions. Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 - Good notes and trackable deposits should keep one safe.